# How to import the exported function of a module asynchronously with dynamic imports and call it?

Tags: typescript, es6-promise, typescript2.0, dynamic-import

in a promise's async callback function

```
promise.then(async callbackResultValue => { //here })
```

I tried

```
const browserd = await import('browser-detect');
if (typeof browserd === 'function') { 
    const browserinfo = browserd();
}
```

got:

> [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
>   Type 'never' has no compatible call signatures.

then I tried:

```
const browserd:Function = await import('browser-detect');
```

got:

> [ts] Type 'typeof import("`<path-to-npm-module>`' is not assignable
>   to type 'Function'.   Property 'apply' is missing in type 'typeof
>   import("`<path-to-npm-module>`'.

Comment: Whats is goal to use this?

Comment: @OPV my current use case is to conditionally load a module, that uses/depends on APIs not supported on all targeted runtimes.

Answer (score 3):

I was just struggling through the same thing and came to find out that object in the returned Promise may not be the function itself, but an object with a property called `default` whose value is the function you want.

As I write this, I still don't fully understand all the nuances of exporting, but this code worked for me:

```
    import('moduleWithADefaultExportOfAFunction')
        .then(theImport => theImport.default());
```